# ruby on rails datetime select not updating db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, datetime, rails-activerecord

im trying to use the builtin ruby helper for datetime select, though it doesnt seem to be passing the values through to ActiveRecord

form.haml.html

```
.row
      .two.columns
        = f.label :date_and_time, :class =>'left inline'
      .ten.columns
        = f.datetime_select('datetime', :prompt => {:day => 'Choose day', :month => 'Choose month', :year => 'Choose year'}, :order => [:day, :month, :year])
```

console output

```
Processing by EventsController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sebpDgAPPmK8q9024vrhN4eEQT7vZLr+pa5XdSicAMc=", "event"=>{"event"=>"1", "location_id"=>"13", "datetime(3i)"=>"5", "datetime(2i)"=>"5", "datetime(1i)"=>"2012", "datetime(4i)"=>"01", "datetime(5i)"=>"03", "duration"=>"34", "arrival_time"=>"34", "team_id"=>"1", "opponent_id"=>"4", "home_or_away"=>"Away"}, "commit"=>"Update Event", "id"=>"68"}
  User Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 38 LIMIT 1
  Event Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "68"]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "68"]]
  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."team_id" = 1
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.9ms)  UPDATE "events" SET "updated_at" = '2013-02-09 11:44:24.830499', "selected_players" = '---
- ''''
' WHERE "events"."id" = 68
   (8.2ms)  COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your label it's `:date_and_time` field in your database, right? If so you should use it in your `datetime_select`:

```
= f.datetime_select :date_and_time, :prompt => {:day => 'Choose day', :month => 'Choose month', :year => 'Choose year'}, :order => [:day, :month, :year])
```

Comment: na the label is different to the actual field in the database

Comment: from what i can see on console the form is passing the hash but activerecord doesnt seem to be seeing it

Answer (score 0):

found the issue was within the controller, still referring to old naming we had in place, since making the change all appears to be working